# Como puedo hacer que el llamado a mi metodo se ejecute despues de 2 segundos?

Tags: c#

Un ejemplo llamo a varios metodos asi:

```
metodo1();
metodos2();
//el siguiente metodo quiero que espere 2 segundos antes de llamarlo y que continue con la ejecucion
metodos4();
//termina la llamada de metodos.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo *durmiendo* tu hilo por la cantidad de tiempo que necesites entre llamadas, utilizando el método [`Thread.Sleep()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.8), al que le pasas la cantidad de milisegundos que debe *dormir* el hilo, por ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        metodo1();
        metodos2();
        //espera de 2 segundos
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        metodos4();
    }

    .. el resto de tu clase
}
```

Comment: Usa un timer, thread. Sleep lo que haces es que duerme el hilo por la cantidad de tiempo indicado como mínimo, si no hay hilos disponible no te devolverá el Co trol hasta que alguno se desocupe

Comment: ¿No te devolverá el control si no hay hilos disponibles en dónde?

Comment: mira esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/391737/3306955

Comment: y  desde la docuementacion de Thread.Sleep(time) The thread will not be scheduled for execution by the operating system for the amount of time specified. This method changes the state of the thread to include WaitSleepJoin.

Comment: Considero que son casos distintos. Para la pregunta del AP, sigo considerando que la llamada a `Sleep()` es lo suficientemente adecuada, sobre todo si, como estoy asumiendo, se llama desde el hilo principal. Si bien, no es la mejor práctica, el caso de uso es lo suficientemente simple y el tiempo de espera lo suficientemente corto como para usar `Sleep()` y no enrollarse tanto.

Comment: Thread.sleep puede ser un buen candidato, pero hace falta saber más si bien en su código muestra una aplicación de consola, si esto se ejecuta en el hilo principal de una aplicación con interfaz gráfica, la interfaz se colgará por 2 segundos, también si va a usar su código en un método asíncrono seria mejor Task.Delay(2000); pero tienes razón para el caso que presenta sleep es perfectamente utilizable